# Proof and transformations

Tags: solution-verification, linear-transformations

So I got this problem:

[image]

I have made a proof, but I'm not sure if it is correct.

$$T(\vec{x})=x_1\cdot T(\vec{e_1})+x_2\cdot T(\vec{e_2})+x_3\cdot T(\vec{e_3})$$

$$S(\vec{x})=x_1\cdot S(\vec{e_1})+x_2\cdot S(\vec{e_2})+x_3\cdot S(\vec{e_3})$$

Then I take:

$T(\vec{x})-S(\vec{x})=x_1\cdot T(\vec{e_1})+x_2\cdot T(\vec{e_2})+x_3\cdot T(\vec{e_3})-x_1\cdot S(\vec{e_1})-x_2\cdot S(\vec{e_2})-x_3\cdot S(\vec{e_3})$$

That can be written as:

$T(\vec{x})-S(\vec{x})=x_1( T(\vec{e_1})-S(\vec{e_1}) )+x_2( T(\vec{e_2})-S(\vec{e_2}) )+x_3( T(\vec{e_3})-S(\vec{e_3}) )$

$T(\vec{x})-S(\vec{x})=0  \rightarrow S(\vec{x})=T(\vec{x})$

Does this seem correct? I'm not a good at proofs so thats the reason why I ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct, but you should have added that $\vec x$ is an arbitrary vector of $\Bbb R^3$ and that $\vec x=x_1\overrightarrow{e_1}+x_2\overrightarrow{e_2}+x_3\overrightarrow{e_3}$.

However, I think that the proof is too long. After having written those expressions for $T\left(\vec x\right)$ and $S\left(\vec x\right)$, you could simply say that, since $T\left(\overrightarrow{e_1}\right)=S\left(\overrightarrow{e_1}\right)$, $T\left(\overrightarrow{e_2}\right)=S\left(\overrightarrow{e_2}\right)$, and $T\left(\overrightarrow{e_3}\right)=S\left(\overrightarrow{e_3}\right)$, the RHS of both expressions are equal.

Comment: Thank you for some good inputs! :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.